# What is the appropriate place to put application log?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm new to linux and would like to know the convention about putting application log.

I have an application call it `myapp`. Now the config file for the `myapp` is located in `/etc/myapp`. Now I run the application as this:

```
myapp 2> myapp_err.txt
```

but I'm not sure if `/etc/myapp` is a conventionally right place for error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/myapp` is **not** an appropriate place to write error logs.

See the Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html), in particular [the section about `/var/log`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOGLOGFILESANDDIRECTORIES).